# Creating a Mock API Platform Using Spring Boot: How to create an API at runtime?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, mocking

Currently, I'm trying to develop a **Mock API platform** in **Spring Boot** that can create a mock RESTful endpoints for developer testing purposes. Specifically, I need to create a system where user can define their custom API endpoints, request and expected responses similar to swagger, mockapi.io, ...

For starter, I try a naive solution which **compile a controller Java class at runtime** and try to access that API endpoint but **not working**. Seem like, the Spring Bean Container cannot understand a new Controller Bean at runtime.

App.java

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        var context = SpringApplication.run(ApiSimulationApplication.class, args);
        CreationService service = new CreationService();
        Path mockControllerPath = service.createMockControllerFile();
        service.compileFile(mockControllerPath);
    }
```

MockController.java (created at runtime)

```
@RestController
public class MockController {
    public MockController() {}

    @GetMapping({"/mock"})
    public String sayHello() {return "Hello";}
}
```

Even if I try to refresh the `ApplicationContex,` it will throw:

> GenericApplicationContext does not support multiple refresh attempts

I could not think of any other solution or may be I have been following the wrong direction, so I am here to seek for advice and recommendations.
**I am looking forward and really appreciate your help.**